# Change DataSource dynamically

Tags: java, datasource

In my xml each query has a own connection (mostly are all the same connection so far), I wanna do something like:
if DataConnection.getConnectionName.equal("current") so don't create a new connection, else create a new one with new data source.
Any suggest how can I accomplish this?

My class:

```
    Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
DataSource ds = null;
public List<Object> searchQuery(String key) {
    
    try {
         ds = (DataSource) Archicon.getResource("jdbc/"+this.getKey(Integer.parseInt(key)).getConnection().getName());
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(this.getKey(Integer.parseInt(key)).getSelect().trim());
    } catch (NamingException | SQLException e) {
        Archicon.getLogger().error("AwpSapNewRepository error: "+e);
    }finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Archicon.getLogger().error("AwpSapNewRepository.searchQuery: errore nella chiusura del resultset su " + e);
        }
        
        try {
            if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Archicon.getLogger().error("AwpSapNewRepository.searchQuery: errore nella chiusura dello statement su " +  e);
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null) conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Archicon.getLogger().error("AwpSapNewRepository.searchQuery: errore nella chiusura della connessione su " +  e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could open one connection (remember where you opened it to) and then process only the parts of your file that use this connection. Afterwards open the next connection and proceed.

Or you could take one entry of your file, check if you already cached a connection. If no, create it and add it to your cache.
Use the cached connection to process the entry, and move on with the next.

Only you can decide which way it is more efficient to process your entries.